# Opening fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment container in main activity. Inside this fragment container, three fragments are changing and are all connected to the navigation bar, like this:

[image]

I want to open another activity when pressing button in Fragment 3 (ProfileFragment). I put the button and wrote this code in ProfileFragment.java:

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SettingsFragment nextFrag= new SettingsFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_profile, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

I don't get an error while opening the application, but after clicking the button, the application closesa dn I get this error:

**ScrollView can host only one direct child.**

But in the XML file, ScrollView already has one child.

The XML file of the Fragment I want to open:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/whiteColor"
tools:context=".FragmentClasses.SettingsFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomsheet_settings"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="25dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
            android:textColor="#686868"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="John"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
            android:textColor="#454545"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/profileLine"/>



</LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

ProfileActivity XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/whiteColor"
android:id="@+id/fragment_profile"
tools:context=".FragmentClasses.ProfileFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile__image_example"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="John"
                android:id="@+id/nameProfile"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter_bold"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#313131"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="USA"
            android:layout_below="@id/nameProfile"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#A7A7A7"
            android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Main Activity XML file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".D.Main_Activity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigationBar"
    app:tabRippleColor="@null"
    app:tabIndicator="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_holo_tablayout"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:tabMinWidth="75dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarFriendpie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainLogo_Friendpie"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/friendpie_text_logo"/>


</RelativeLayout>


<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigationBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarFriendpie" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And lastly, this is the logcat error:

```
Process: com.example.test_friendpie, PID: 16929
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:446)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
```

What is the problem? Thank you for all.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I changed ScrollView with RelativeLayout in my ProfileActivity and wrote ScrollView under RelativeLayout. I don't know why the previous one failed but this works.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun But ScrollView doesn't have one Linear Layout child? All other layouts or components are in my LinearLayout.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed it! Are you adding any view dynamically to the view?

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Nope, I just want to view this fragment in my fragment container. I updated the post, can you look fragment container, is there any problem there?

Comment: can you post xml code that has ScrollView? Also post the logs

Comment: Share your complete error. Also, share the layout containing the `ScrollView`. The error comes when you switch to `SettingsFragment`, maybe it has the `ScrollView` which gives the error.

Comment: I updated the post now, I posted my XML files, can you look? Thank you @User9211

Comment: @KaanFırat Are you adding something to scrollViw at runtime like this - scrollView.addView( .... )   ?  If so, then that's the reason

Comment: @User9211 No, I didn't add. Could I be getting an error because my Profile Fragment is a ScrollView?

Comment: In your button click listener put this code -                                         
            SettingsFragment nextFrag= new SettingsFragment();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_profile, nextFrag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

Comment: @User9211 I have already written this code. But I solved my problem, thank you for your efforts. I changed ScrollView with RelativeLayout in my ProfileActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method you're calling inside your listener removes all *fragments*, from a given container, before replacing them with the provided fragment, adding the new fragment's root `View` to the layout. In this particular case, the Activity's root view is a `ScrollView` which already has a `LinearLayout` child. This `LinearLayout` is, however, not a different fragment's layout, and as such is not removed when calling `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. As a result, when adding the new fragment's layout to the container view, you're effectively calling `ScrollView.addView()` on a `ScrollView` which already has a direct child. I can see two ways of solving your exception (which one fits better with your design/layout is for you to decide):

1. Have the ProfileActivity layout be just the `ScrollView` (essentially delete the `LinearLayout` under it). This is not really ideal, since it adds a `ScrollView` (your fragment's root View) child to another `ScrollView`, making either one redundant. You should either change the fragment's root View not to be a `Scrollview`, or
2. Change the ProfileActivity's root View not to be a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Second solution is works for me. Thank you for your time.